# Django 1.6.1 and South

Tags: django, postgresql, django-south

I am using south in my Django application and can't understand one thing. I have changed one field from IntegerField to CharField and made after it : manage.py app_name --auto --update. Then I looked at the list of migrations  and saw that this migration has number 0014. But when I do manage.py app_name migrate south tries to migrate version 0004. How to specify 0014?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you meant:

```
manage.py schemamigration app_name --auto --update
```

not

```
manage.py app_name --auto --update
```

You can specify a version with the migrate:

```
./manage.py migrate app_name 0014
```

or the full version name:

```
./manage.py migrate myapp 0014_change_charfield...
```